# iOS: Coding tips to prevent redundancy

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a `UITableView` that is going to act as a settings view controller. Obviously its going to have a few types of input. One cell might have a slider, one might drill down to another view controller, one with a textbox etc. Is there any way to avoid making umpteen different subclasses for `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: You can always have one UITableViewCell creating it's views programmatically based on an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this github project: [QuickDialog](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog).